# How do you replace a line in a text file containing a specific value (batch)

Tags: batch-file

The point of this batch script is to take a user entered account number and replace the line in the text file containing that account number with something like "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx". How would I go about doing that? Right now it is just displaying the account information of the account number.

```
set /p acct_code=Enter account code:
echo.
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set flag=0
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=," %%r in (accounts.txt) do (
if %%r==!acct_code! (
cls
echo Account Information
echo ******************* 
echo Account Code : %%r
echo Account Name : %%s
echo Account Balance : %%t
set flag=1
)
)
if !flag!==0 echo Account NOT Found, Please Try Again...
echo.
PAUSE
cls
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you missed just the code to write the line again (to a new file):

```
...
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=," %%r in (accounts.txt) do (
  if %%r==!acct_code! (
    cls
    echo Account Information
    echo ******************* 
    echo Account Code : %%r
    echo Account Name : %%s
    echo Account Balance : %%t
    echo(%r,%%s,%%t >>accounts.new
    set flag=1
  ) else (
    echo xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>>accounts.new
  )
)
ECHO move /y accounts.new accounts.txt
...
```

(Note: to actually rename the new file (overwrite the original file), remove the `ECHO` before `move`)

Comment: @Avoxy If this answer solved your problem you should accept it.